# Google Analytics Tracking Code Will Not Fire on "3rd Party" Domain

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

The tracking code on the site in question, "site2", appears as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'site1.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the debugger on that site:

[image: Screesnhot of GA Debug]

The _setDomainName method on the preceding domain, "site1" has a period before it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.site1.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

While this may or may not prevent cookies from being passed along to the second domain, the tracking code should still at least fire, no? **It is important to note that we own both domains**. I cannot find any reason that would cause the code not to trigger, except perhaps an error elsewhere on the page. I am using GA Debug to see whether or not the beacon is being sent. It's being sent on site1, but not on site2.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_setDomainName` tells the Google Analytics cookie where to store itself.  Browsers will not let set a cookie on `site1.com` from `site2.com`.  Leave `.site1.com` on you main site and update it to `.site2.com` on your second.

If you'd like visit data between domains, you have to do one of the following:

- Tag the links between the domains using linkByPost etc... Read the google documentation about it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite
- OR I'd recommend looking into Google Analytics on Steroids as they solve this use case more elegantly: https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas#cross-domain

Comment: I don't know if I've been clear. The two script snippets are on two different sites/pages, they aren't being called twice. Second, if you look at the setDomainName values, the domain is the same on both sites; the only difference being the preceding "." Either way, the tracking code should still fire.

Comment: @Analyticus Just reworded above

Comment: This statement is factually wrong "The destination page (on site2) needs to contain the same setDomainName as the origin site, or the cookies will be overwritten"

Comment: I *am* capable of being wrong ;), but what about the code not firing? Worst case scenario, the cookies should just be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you need the period before the domain name. According to the google analytics guide you should use the following formatting.

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example-petstore.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainSubDomains

Comment: Yes, and despite telling the developers that, they left it in. I understand why; Google Analytics documentation formerly included that. Either way though, at worst that should reset the cookie, not prevent the tracker from firing. Attached is a screenshot of the debugger

Comment: I do not see the screenshot. Did it attach?

Comment: Is the SS different for the second site?

Comment: Yes, the tracking beacon is being fired on the origin site.